# Merge columns with same id mysql

Tags: mysql

I created a view, the following image is the query of it:

```
select * from order_extended
```

[image: order_extended]

Is there a way to merge the products_id that are the same? something like this:

```
+-----+----------+----------------+---------+------+------+
| pid | quantity | product_name   | Walmart | Sams | Ley  |
+-----+----------+----------------+---------+------+------+
|   1 |   1.00   | ACEITE CAPULLO | 27.50   | 24.33| 29.90|
|   3 |   2.00   | ACEITE DE AJONJ| 40.00   | null | null | 
|   5 |   2.00   | ACEITE DE COCO | 114.00  | null | null | 
+-----+----------+----------------+---------+------+------+
```

This is the view definition:

```
create view order_extended as (
SELECT ol.products_id, ol.quantity, p.product_name, p.brand, 
case when s.name = "WALMART" then sp.purchase_price end as Walmart,
case when s.name = "SAMS" then sp.purchase_price end as Sams,
case when s.name = "LEY" then sp.purchase_price end as Ley,

FROM order_lists ol 
inner join products p on ol.products_id = p.id
inner join supplier_products sp on p.id = sp.products_id
inner join suppliers s on sp.supplier_id = s.id
);
```

Comment: How do you want to merge rows that have multiple entries in the Walmart column for a particular products_id? Do you want to improve your view or write a new query? To improve your view, we need the data and query for that.

Comment: Show the definition of your view. I suspect it could be easily changed to achieve the desired results using a group by.

Comment: I was trying to query the view to merge the rows and get the table that I drew, I updated the post with the definition  of the view.